# Оператор break для switch case внутри lambda-выражения

Tags: java, lambda, switch

Прошу подсказать, как можно обыграть такую ситуацию с break:

```
...    
List<MyDTO> myDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
someList.forEach(element -> {
    switch (elenemt.getStatus()) {
        case "SUCCESS":
            myDtoList.add(new MyDTO().setSuccessStatus(true));
            break;
        case "ERROR":
            myDtoList.add(new MyDTO().setSuccessStatus(false));
            break;
    }
});
```

Проблема в том, что когда выполняется break, происходит прерывание выполнения forEach

Comment: В данной ситуации помогает использование return вместо break, но, к сожалению, я не понимаю почему так работает. Документацию или хорошую статью на эту тему найти не могу.

Answer (score 0):

```
someList.forEach(e -> {
    switch (element .getStatus()) {
        case "SUCCESS":
            myDtoList.add(new MyDTO().setSuccessStatus(true));
            break;
        case "ERROR":
            myDtoList.add(new MyDTO().setSuccessStatus(false))
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + e.getIsBlocked());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Я не понимаю чем полезен Ваш ответ, кроме того, здесь добавлена обработка иного значения? В своём вопросе я максимально упростил код, чтобы показать суть проблемы.

Comment: я запустил он нормально отработал с break

Answer (score 0):

Избавимся от `switch` и `break` и проблема решена:

```
List<MyDTO> myDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
someList.forEach(element -> {
    myDtoList.add( new MyDTO().setSuccessStatus(element.getStatus() == "SUCCESS")) );
});
```